# How to ensure consistency and efficiency in distributed systems, such as Dynamo like models

Tags: storage, system, distributed, cnosdb

In distributed systems, models like Dynamo do not have a master node. Although it simplifies the writing method, some strategies are usually adopted to achieve consistency during reading. How does CnosDB do this?

In the mode of unowned replication, it is difficult to do data subscription and synchronization. How does CnosDB sometimes do it?